# How to get the normal acceleration

Tags: dynamics, acceleration

For the problem below, I tried solving it, but I don't know where I should get the value of normal acceleration, guess I was lost.[image]

[image]
And here's what I solved so far
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

In order to calculate the tangential and the normal acceleration you need to take them as vectors.

[image]

The angles are

- $\theta= \arctan(16/12)=-53.13 deg$ for velocity
- $\phi= \arctan(16/12)=-26.51 deg$ for accelaration

Therefore the vectors for acceleration and velocity would be

[image]

And then you can find the component of tangential and normal acceleration as:

- **tangential:** $a_t =a \cos(\theta-\phi)$
- **normal:** $a_n =a \sin(\theta-\phi) = 5\frac{m}{s^2}$

Then you can just substitute:

$$R = \frac{v^2}{a_n}= \frac{20^2}{5}= \frac{400}{5}= 80 in$$

Comment: Help appreciated, arigatou

Comment: Itsu demo dohzo